# ngSubmit not working inside modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

It seems that my submit button is not activating the ng-click angular directive and I cannot figure out why. It seems that every other person that had this problem didn't include their submit button inside of their form, and I'm 99% sure I did that.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="subModal" ng-controller="SubscriberController" ng-controller-as="subCtrl">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times; </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Subscribe</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="well">
                            <form ng-submit="console.log('submit')">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subscriber-name" class="control-label"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subCtrl.subData.name" placeholder="John Doe" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="subscriber-email" class="control-label"><strong>Email:</strong></label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="subCtrl.subData.email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i> Subscribe</button>
                                </div>
                                <div re-captcha ng-model="subCtrl.subData.captcha"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put something like

```
<input ng-model="myForm.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="subCtrl.subData.email" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required>
```

and

```
<input ng-model="myForm.name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="subCtrl.subData.name" placeholder="John Doe" required>
```

into your inputs, and give your form a name attribute

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="submit()">
```

plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/KRmZkPS6t4ANmAHwTevQ