# AngularJS submit form from modal

Tags: angularjs

I've a form into a modal window (created using Angular UI Bootstrap).

My form has this code:

```
<form ng-submit="processForm()" name="form2" role="form">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="ckCS" name="ckCS" />
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Then in my controller I've this code:

```
.controller(
    'ModalInstanceCtrl', 
    function ($scope, $modalInstance, $http, sharedProperties, items) {
         $scope.processForm = function () {
              //[here I've some code with http.post]
              $modalInstance.close();
         }
     }
)
```

Modal is showing without problem, but when I try to submit the form it simply doesn't work. It doesn't show errors even in console log.

The controller of my modal window is set in this way:

```
$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

        $scope.open = function (size) {

            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                size: size,
                resolve: {
                    items: function () {
                        return $scope.items;
                    }
                }
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                $scope.selected = selectedItem;
            }, function () {
                //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
            });
        };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could try just having an ng-click="processForm()" in your button element?

Comment: Is the controller of your HTML 'ModalInstanceCtrl'?

Comment: @uksz I update my question in a minute.

Comment: @Henry00 tried your solution, but it still not working.

Comment: Need to check $scope.processForm() is invoked on the submit? Keep a comment for console.log and remove http post code and keep only  $modalInstance.close();

Comment: @RajkumarRathi I followed your suggestion, but processForm is never invoked on submit. And no error in console log.

Comment: check if controller is in under the same module as others

Comment: @RajkumarRathi I'll check asap. The weird fact is if I use $scope.ok and $scope.cancel function it works (well, still not executing http.post, but it works with modal.close)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544307/ngsubmit-not-working-inside-modal